# CRM 2011 LINQ OrganizationServiceContext Tracking

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011

Create 2 Contacts in CRM UI, one has FirstName "fn1", LastName "ln1", second has FirstName "fn2", LastName "ln2"

CRMServerContext is the OrganizationServiceContext.

```
List<Contact> firstNameContacts = (from c in CRMServerContext.CreateQuery<Contact>()
                                   where c.FirstName == "fn1" || c.FirstName == "fn2"
                                   select c).ToList();


foreach (var c in firstNameContacts)
{
   bool attached = CRMServerContext.IsAttached(c);
}

List<Contact> lastNameContacts = (from c in CRMServerContext.CreateQuery<Contact>()
                                  where c.LastName == "ln1" || c.LastName == "ln2"
                                  select c).ToList();

foreach (var c in firstNameContacts)
{
   bool attached = CRMServerContext.IsAttached(c);
}
```

In the first foreach "attached" is true for each of the contacts returned which are the 2 created in the UI.

Next retrieve the same two contacts but using LastName as criteria.

This results in the second foreach reporting "attached" is false even though it is iterating through the same List as the first and no modifications have been made to the list?

The two contacts are returned by both queries, shouldn't the context still report "attached" as being true?

Comment: Just a note, the second foreach is also from the firstNameContacts, right? so you're not using lastNameContacts at all... Anyway, if you are still using the same list I don't see why it's being modified..

Comment: Yes, the second foreach is using firstNameContacts which demonstrates the issue. I would expect for these contacts to still return as being attached by the context. But by having that second query which pulls back the same contacts but by different criteria it appears to "detach" the original contacts as in firstNameContacts even though they are the same contacts as retreived in the second query.

Comment: LINQ is executed when you use it, not when you declare it. This way, the query will be run when doing the foreach. This might end up having different behaviour if the items are modified between those cases, but if you are not modifying the list, the I have no clue what it's happening. Sorry.

Comment: The ToList() forces the evaluation of the LINQ expression which is how the foreach can then be executed and show differing results.

Comment: you're right, I didn't realize about the ToList(). Still, even if the query is run again, he says that he hasn't changed anything, so the same query should return the same results...